# Overriding react components styles with styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I tried to override style of component created by standard way of styled-components(styled.) and both the ways(`styled()` and `style.extends`) worked for me.

But when I am trying to override style of simple react component with `styled()` approach, its rendering the component but not overriding it's style.

Below is snippet of code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default class MyLabel extends Component {
  render() {
    return <label>{this.props.children}</label>;
  }
}

const StyledMyLabel = styled(MyLabel)`
    color: green;
`;
```

And for display purpose I am using following syntax

```
<StyledMyLabel>My Styled Label</StyledMyLabel>
```

Please refer the [link on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zlv5o3l9yp) which might be useful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to pass `className` to desirable styling element manually to make it works.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default class MyLabel extends Component {
  render() {
    return <label className={this.props.className}>{this.props.children}</label>;
  }
}

const StyledMyLabel = styled(MyLabel)`
    color: green;
`;
```

**NOTE**:

> Consider carefully whether to wrap your own components in a styled component, when it isn't necessary. You will disable the automatic whitelisting of props, and reverse the recommended order of styled components and structural components.

See more info [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components).

Comment: Updating the link...this one goes to some related info: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components

Answer (score 0):

```
<label style={{color: "green"}}>{this.props.children}</label>
```

or

```
const style = {color : "green"};
<label style={style}>{this.props.children}</label>
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this is not the correct answer?

Comment: @YigitAlparslan people tend to use styled-component not to use inline-style to keep components clean, so the answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to accomplish this when you want to override a component with pre-existing styles.

Each Component in react comes with a theme property.

```
//the component you are trying to change the style of
import { AppBar } from 'react-toolbox/lib/app_bar';

//your stylesheet for the new component
import newTheme from './NewAppBar.css'

//inject your new stylesheet for the existing component
<AppBar {...props} theme={newTheme} />
```