# Styled component not wrapping another styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `Popup` component like so:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Div = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
`;

const Popup = ({ isOpen, onClose, children }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const onClick = e => {
      if (isOpen && onClose) {
        onClose();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
  }, [isOpen, onClose]);

  return <Div>
    {isOpen && children}
  </Div>;
};

export default Popup;
```

Now I'm trying to wrap it into another styled component:

```
const Menu = styled(Popup)`
  background-color: red;
`;
```

But using this `Menu` only applies the styles from the `Popup`, i.e. the background color stays white. Why isn't it changing to red?

Comment: check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871930/overriding-react-components-styles-with-styled-component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `className` prop to `Popup` component in order to allow the css-in-js library (`styled-component`) to inject its styles:

```
const Popup = ({ isOpen, onClose, children, className }) => {
  //...
  return <Div className={className}>{isOpen && children}</Div>;
};
```

See **Styling normal React components** in [Docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components).